# "Mazing" Into a secret room?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I started a run (curse of the maze) and when I walked out of the item room (the first room I went into) I teleported into the secret room. From my experience, curse of the maze only messes up rooms in the same row/column on the map, however the secret room was not opened and was not adjacent to any room I had previously been in. Is this normal, or has this happened to anybody else?

Comment: This is an a"Mazing" break through!

Comment: I don't know what else to call it. I guess it's technically teleporting, but then people would think I'm talking about telepills or something.

Comment: Yeah, that happened to me as well. It also happened with the shop and the curse room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's normal, I've been teleported into curse rooms with curse of the maze( and I had no hp left to exit at that time), or into a boss room on the complete other side of the level. If my memory isn't failing me I even teleported into an item shop through it once.

I'm pretty sure curse of the maze can teleport you anywhere, but it has a high chance of teleporting you a room backwards or some other room nearby. There is a low chance of being thrown into any room on the level.

Comment: I can confirm that.Curse of the Maze teleports you into any random room.